# How is NokiaHere Geocoding Score calculated?

Tags: geocoding, here-maps

When geocoding an address in NokiaHere, a Component Score is calculated according to the information provided in the original address.

Example:

> {"componentsScore": {"CITY": 1.0, "COUNTRY": 1.0, "DISTRICT": 1.0,
>   "HOUSE_NUMBER": 1.0, "POSTAL_CODE": 0.0, "STATE": 0.0, "STREET": 1.0},
>   "totalScore": 0.92}

If you could provide any information on the way this estimation is made, it would very helpful.